# How to get Multi-Step form validation working for password?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

alright so for starters, i am using using https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps as the base of my form with modifications to it (see Below) validation is working properly if the fields are blank the next button does not work however if i try to add pattern required for password it does nothing. could anyone help? note: i do have a second script "vue.js' this is to display which of the [Requirements have been fulfilled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl9Sx.png) (also had to remove a chunk of code from last step due to word count limits

```html
 <form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">


  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">

            <h3  class="text-center">Lets Get You Registered</h3>

<div class=" pt-25 pb-30  container">

                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 ">
                    <h3>Billing Information</h3>
                    <!--<div class="choose-us-image">
                            <img src="images/other/left.png" alt="">
                        </div>-->

<ul>
    <li style="width: 48%"><label>First Name:</label><br><input type="textt" name="FirstName"></li>
    <li style="width: 49%"><label style="padding-top:7px;">Last Name:</label><br><input type="textt" Name="LastName"></li>
    <li style="width: 98%"><label style="padding-top:7px;">Address:</label><br><input type="textt" name="Address"></li>
<!--    <li style="width: 65%"><label style="padding-top:7px;">Address 2:</label><br><input type="textt" id="address2" name="adress2" style="display: none;"  ></li>-->
    <li><label style="padding-top:7px;">City:</label><br> <input style="width:125px; " type="textt" name="City"></li>
    <li ><label style="padding-top:7px;">State:</label><br> <input style="width:65px; " maxlength="2" type="textt" name="State"></li>
    <li><label style="padding-top:7px;">Zip Code:</label><br> <input style="width:76px; " type="textt"></li>
        <li style="width: 35%"><label>Phone Number:</label><br><input type="textt"></li>

</ul>




                </div>
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 pull-right ">
                    <h3>Account Setup</h3>
                    <!--<div class="choose-us-image">
                            <img src="images/other/left.png" alt="">
                        </div>-->

<ul>
        <li style="width: 100%"><label style="padding-top:7px;">Email:</label><br><input type="textt" name="Email"></li>
    <li style="width: 100%"><label>Username</label><br><input type="textt" name="Username"></li>


    <li style="width: 100%"><div id="app" >

        <label class="
                      " for="password">Password</label>
        <input placeholder="Enter your password" name="password" id="pass" class="frmField"  type="password"  @input="password_check" v-model="message" required/>
        <label class="contained">Show Password
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()"/>
            <span class="checkmark"></span> <a style="font-size: 10px; float: right;" href="#containx" data-reveal-id="exampleModal"> Already Have a account? Sign in <u>here</u></a></label>





        <p class="frmValidation" :class="{'frmValidation--passed' : message.length > 7}"><i class="frmIcon fas" :class="message.length > 7 ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-times'"></i> Longer than 7 characters</p>
        <p class="frmValidation" :class="{'frmValidation--passed' :has_uppercase }"><i class="frmIcon fas" :class="has_uppercase ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-times'"></i> Has a capital letter</p>
        <p class="frmValidation" :class="{'frmValidation--passed' :has_lowercase }"><i class="frmIcon fas" :class="has_lowercase ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-times'"></i> Has a lowercase letter</p>
        <p class="frmValidation" :class="{'frmValidation--passed' : has_number }"><i class="frmIcon fas" :class="has_number ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-times'"></i> Has a number</p>
        <p class="frmValidation" :class="{'frmValidation--passed' : has_special }"><i class="frmIcon fas" :class="has_special ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-times'"></i> Has a special character</p>
    </div></li>



</ul>




                </div>
      </div>
       <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)" style="float:left;">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)"  style="float:right;">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
     <h3  class="text-center">Next, Lets Choose a plan</h3>
        <div class="row ptb-40">
                    <!-- Pricing table single -->
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 res-pb-xs-30">
                        <div class="pricing-table-single white-bg">
                            <div class="table-category text-center">
                                <h6>Silver pack</h6>
                                <h1>$30<span> / month</span></h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pricing-list text-center">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">30 messages</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">One number</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Null</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Null</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Null</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-button text-uppercase text-center" onclick="nextPrev(1)">
                                <a onclick="base();" >Select</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Pricing table single -->
                    <!-- Pricing table single -->
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 res-pb-xs-30">
                        <div class="pricing-table-single white-bg">
                            <div class="table-category text-center">
                                <h6>gold pack</h6>
                                <h1>$50<span> / month</span></h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pricing-list text-center">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">50 messages</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Two Numbers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Null</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Null</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Null</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-button text-uppercase text-center" onclick="nextPrev(1)">
                                <a onclick="pro();">Select</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Pricing table single -->
                    <!-- Pricing table single -->
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 res-pb-xs-30">
                        <div class="pricing-table-single white-bg">
                            <div class="table-category text-center">
                                <h6>platinum pack</h6>
                                <h1>$90<span> / month</span></h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pricing-list text-center">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Unlimited Messages</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Unlimited Numbers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Null</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Null</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Null</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-button text-uppercase text-center" onclick="nextPrev(1)">
                                <a onclick="ent();">Select</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Pricing table single -->
                                <!-- Pricing table single -->
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 res-pb-xs-30">
                        <div class="pricing-table-single white-bg">
                            <div class="table-category text-center">
                                <h6>platinum pack</h6>
                                <h1>$90<span> / month</span></h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pricing-list text-center">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Unlimited Messages</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Unlimited Numbers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Null</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Null</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Null</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-button text-uppercase text-center" onclick="nextPrev(1)">
                                <a onclick="payg();">Select</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Pricing table single -->
                </div>
 <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)" style="float:left;">Previous</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
       <h3  class="text-center">Finally, Lets take care of payment</h3>

<div class=" pt-25 pb-30  container">

                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 ">
                    <h3>Billing Information</h3>
                    <!--<div class="choose-us-image">
                            <img src="images/other/left.png" alt="">
                        </div>-->

<ul>
    <li style="width: 48%"><label>First Name:</label><br><input name="BillingFirstname" type="textt"></li>
    <li style="width: 49%"><label style="padding-top:7px;">Last Name:</label><br><input name="BillingLastname" type="textt"></li>
    <li style="width: 98%"><label style="padding-top:7px;">Address:</label><br><input Name="Billingaddress" type="textt" class=""></li>
<!--    <li style="width: 65%"><label style="padding-top:7px;">Address 2:</label><br><input type="textt" id="address2" name="adress2" style="display: none;"  ></li>-->
    <li><label style="padding-top:7px;">City:</label><br> <input style="width:125px; " name="Billingcity" type="textt"></li>
    <li ><label style="padding-top:7px;">State:</label><br> <input style="width:65px; " maxlength="2" type="textt" name="BillingState"></li>
    <li><label style="padding-top:7px;">Zip Code:</label><br> <input style="width:76px; " type="textt" name="BillingZipcode"></li>
        <li style="width: 35%"><label>Phone Number:</label><br><input type="textt" name="BillingPhone"></li>

</ul>




                </div>
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 pull-right ">
<h3 >Payment Information</h3>
<ul>
    <li><label>Name on Card:</label><br><input  type="textt"  name="Nameoncard"></li>
    <li style="width:187px"><label style="padding-top:7px;">Card Number</label><br><input maxlength="16"  type="textt" name="Cardnumber"></li>
    <li style="width:26%;padding-right:7px;"><label style="padding-top:7px;">Security Code</label><br><input maxlength="4" type="textt" name="SecurityCode"></li>
     <li><label style="padding-top:7px;padding-bottom:8px;">Expiration Date</label><br><div class="custom-select" style="width:101px;" name="Expdate">
  <select>
    <option value="0">Month</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
      <option value="10">October</option>
      <option value="10">November</option>
      <option value="10">December</option>

  </select>
</div></li>
    <li><div class="custom-select" style="width:75px;">
        <select name="">
    <option value="yr">Year</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
    <option value="2023">2023</option>
    <option value="2024">2024</option>
    <option value="2025">2025</option>
    <option value="2026">2026</option>
    <option value="2027">2027</option>
    <option value="2028">2028</option>
    <option value="2029">2029</option>
    <option value="2030">2030</option>
    <option value="2031">2031</option>
    <option value="2032">2032</option>
    <option value="2033">2033</option>
    <option value="2034">2034</option>
    <option value="2035">2035</option>
    <option value="2036">2036</option>
    <option value="2037">2037</option>
    <option value="2038">2038</option>
    <option value="2039">2039</option>
 <option value="2039">2040</option>

        </select></div></li>

</ul>




                </div>





    <!--------Plan Specific-------------------->




<!----------------------------------------------------------------------
<!--------- Plan Specific END------------>

      </div>
 <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)" style="float:left;">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" value="submit"  style="float:right;">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
            </div>

 <!-- <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)" style="float:left;">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)"  style="float:right;">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>-->
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
   <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:10px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    </div>
</form>

    <div class="" id="containx">
  <div action="/action_page.php" id="exampleModal" class="reveal-modal" style="background-color: white;">
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="textt" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

    <label for=""><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="" required>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
    <a href="#" class="close-reveal-modal pt-10"  style="float: right;"> Back to Sign-Up</a>
  </div>
</div>
       <script>

        var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the crurrent tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
    
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}


        </script>
        
            <script>        let app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data:{
                message:       '',
                has_number:    false,
                has_lowercase: false,
                has_uppercase: false,
                has_special:   false,
            },
            methods: {
                password_check: function () {
                    this.has_number    = /\d/.test(this.message);
                    this.has_lowercase = /[a-z]/.test(this.message);
                    this.has_uppercase = /[A-Z]/.test(this.message);
                    this.has_special   = /[!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]/.test(this.message);
                }
            },
        }); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

added these to the function details

```js
var paswd=  /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{8,15}$/;

inputtxt = document.getElementById("pass")
```

Also, added this to the validate form function

```js
    if(inputtxt.value.match(paswd))
{
valid = true;
}
else
{
document.getElementById("err").innerHTML = ('Your Password did not fulfill requirements listed below');
valid = false;
}
```

Worked like a charm!

Sources:
https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/password-validation.php
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_output_dom